# How to display thumbnails generated with pagerAnchorBuilder in 3 columns

Tags: jquery

I have created a slideshow using a jQuery Cycle plugin and pagerAnchorBuilder to generate thumbnails.

The thumbs are correctly generated and the slideshow is functioning. However, the thumbnails are shown vertically flowing over the div in which they are supposed to be in.

I'd like them to break up into 3 columns so that they fit in the div. In addition, I need to do 2 other things besides #1:

1. Make thumbnails into 3 columns
2. Use opacity effect of 1 on the activeSlide and on mouseOver, and .50 on mouseOut
3. Create caption for each image in the slideshow.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        speed: 3000, 
        timeout: 3000, 
        next:   '.slideshow', 
        pause:   1,
        pager:  '#thumbnavigator',
        slideExpr: 'img',
        // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="40" height="40" /></a></li>'; 
        }
    });
});
```